# React Native S3 Upload to presigned URL ~ image being saved as a json object instead of image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, axios

I am working on a script to upload an image to S3 in react native, react-native-imagepicker, and axios...

To start, I have my file selector:

```
 function onChoosePhoto() {
    const options = {
      noData: true,
    }
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (!response.didCancel && !response.error) setFile(response)
    })
  }
```

then after the file has been set I send it to my service:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const isValidSize = file && file.fileSize > 6 * 1024;
  const isValidType = file && allowedTypes.includes(file.type);
  if (isValidSize && isValidType) {
    setErrors([]);
    uploadFile(file);
  } else {
    if (file && !isValidSize) setErrors([...errors, 'file exceeds maximum allowed size']);
    if (file && !isValidType) setErrors([...errors, 'unsupported file type, please use a jpg file extension']);
  }
}, [file]);
```

and then my service gets the presigned URL and submits the file...

```
export async function receiptUpload(file) {
  const date = new Date();
  const headers = await getAWSHeaders();

  const presignUrl = await request.post(
      urls.fileUpload.presignUpload,
      {file_name: date.getTime()},
      {headers}
    )
    .then(res => res.data);

  const fileUpload = presignUrl.presignUrl && await request.put(
      presignUrl.presignUrl,
      {...file, fileName: date.getTime()}
    )
    .then(res => res.status === 200);

  // const fileId = fileUpload && await request.post(urls.fileUpload.receiptUpload, {file_name: file.name}, {headers}).then(res => res.data);
  // const receiptSubmit = fileId && await request.post(urls.fileUpload.receiptSubmit, {
  //   file_id: fileId.file_id
  // }, {headers}).then(res => res.data);
  return receiptSubmit;
}
```

This seems to be working ok, and I get a 200 response from S3. However when I look in the bucket, it is saving as a file with no file extension and when opening the file it just contains JSON that matches what is given by react-native-imagepicker like this:

```
{
  height: 3024
  origURL: "assets-library://asset/asset.HEIC?id=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&ext=HEIC"
  fileName: null
  width: 4032
  type: "image/jpeg"
  fileSize: 13712705
  isVertical: false
  uri: "file:///Users/sandra.willford/Library/Developer/...
}
```